# can we skip/jump in array while displaying PHP

Tags: php, arrays, drupal, wildcard

I have a multidimensional array returned by drupal render function in that array i want to choose some last values
for example

```
$array['static_name'][number]['changes_every_time']['some_name']['value_i_need'];
```

is there ant way we can skip the "changes_every_time" level while printing array
is there a way we can use wild character in there

like if i want to print

```
echo $array['static_name'][number][*]['some_name'][value_i_need];
```

some thing like this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store answer "no".

But what you can do is do a foreach over the keys of $array['static_name'][number]

```
foreach($array['static_name'][number] as $val) {
   echo $val['some_name'][value_i_need];
}
```

This way you don't have to care.

Answer (score 0):

well, you cold iterate the array at that "level" with a [foreach loop](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)

Untested code:

```
 foreach ($array['static_name'][number] as $key => $value) {
    echo $value['some_name'][value_i_need];
}
```